# Select Box .. after reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<form>
    <select name='myfield' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
      <option>Milk</option>
      <option>Coffee</option>
      <option>Tea</option>
   </select>
    <noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript>
</form>
```

how can i set the selected option after reload..or submit?
because after the submit it will come back to the default ... So what i want is it will be selected even the submit or reload happens... Thank in advance.. ^_^

Comment: How do you generate the HTML? Use the `selected` attribute for the option you want to be the default.

Comment: use `$('select').val(your_value);`

Comment: Try using `local storage` to keep your selection saved

Comment: First of all I want to thank for all of your concern..and second What do you mean local storage ma'am angela?

Answer (score 1):

Get the select:

```
var select=document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
```

Then whenever it is changed, store its value:

```
select.addEventListener("change",function(){
  localStorage.setItem("select",select.selectedIndex);
});
```

Then you just need to re set it at page load:

```
var before=localStorage.getItem("select");
if(before){
  select.options[+before].selected=true;
}
```

Alltogether:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
  var select=document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];

  var before=localStorage.getItem("select");
  if(before){
    select.options[+before].selected=true;
  }

  select.addEventListener("change",function(){
    localStorage.setItem("select",select.selectedIndex);
  });
});
```

[In action](http://jsbin.com/biwixehobe/edit?output)

Comment: I love seeing POJS.

Comment: Sir thanks ,but  is it okay.. If you convert it in java script or atleast in php form..Please , cause I'm still new and still learning about programming

Answer (score 0):

Local storage is a storage, where you can save your data locally within your browser. The data storage remains without getting expired even after you reload your page.

```
   <select name='myfield' id="selectOptions" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
       <option>Milk</option>
       <option>Coffee</option>
       <option>Tea</option>
   </select> 

   document.getElementById("selectOptions").onchange = function() {
        localStorage.setItem('selectedData', document.getElementById("selectOptions").value);
    }

   var storedData = localStorage.getItem('selectedData');
```

By this way you can store your required data in the local storage. 
For more information about local storage, you may have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) link.